# PHP not Accessing Database on Server

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am having difficulty getting my PHP code to reference my database and display certain information within it. The error I am getting is "Unable to access database." I have poured over this code numerous times and cannot seem to find the solution. The first file (Approve Deny Prayer Request) references another file (Prayer Request) in order to draw the data. The idea is that I would be able to edit prayer requests and then click an "Approved" button that would edit the entry and re-save it into the database. Below please find both CGI files.

Thanks for the help.

Approve Deny Prayer Request

```
<table cellpadding="10">
<tr>
<td>First Name</td>
<td>Last Name</td>
<td>Prayer Request</td>
</tr>

<?php

$username="XXXXXX";
$password="XXXXXXXXX";
$database="prayer";

mysqli_connect('fbcaltusprayerorg.ipagemysql.com',$username,$password,$database);
@mysqli_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
$query="SELECT * FROM Request";
$result=mysqli_query($query);
mysqli_close();

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo ("<tr><td>$row[Reg_F_Name]</td>");
echo ("<td>$row[Reg_L_Name]</td>");
echo ("<td>$row[Reg_Request]</td>");
echo ("<td><a href=\"cgi-bin/PrayerRequest.php?id=$row[id]\">Edit</a></td></tr>");
}
echo "</table>";

?>
```

Prayer Request

```
<?php

$username="XXXXX";
$password="XXXXXXXX";
$database="prayer";

mysqli_connect('fbcaltusprayerorg.ipagemysql.com',$username,$password,$database);
@mysqli_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
$query = "SELECT * FROM Request"; 
$result = mysqli_query($query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
?>

<form method="post" action="cgi-bin/ApproveDenyPrayerRequest.php" />

<table>

<tr>
<td>First Name:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="first" value="<? echo "$row[Reg_F_Name]" ?>"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Last Name:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="last" value="<? echo "$row[Reg_L_Name]" ?>"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Prayer Request</td>
<td><input type="text" name="phone" value="<? echo "$row[Reg_Request]" ?>"></td>
</tr>

</table>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use error suppression operator `@` , it will hide the warnings and you will not be able to figure where the problem is..

#### Rewrite your code like this for establishing the connection..

```
<?php

$username="XXXXX";
$password="XXXXXXXX";
$database="prayer";

$link = mysqli_connect('fbcaltusprayerorg.ipagemysql.com', $username, $password, $database);

if (!$link) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
        . mysqli_connect_error());
}

echo 'Success... ' . mysqli_get_host_info($link) . "\n";

$query = "SELECT * FROM Request";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$query); //<----- Added link
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
?>

<form method="post" action="cgi-bin/ApproveDenyPrayerRequest.php" />

<table>

    <tr>
        <td>First Name:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="first" value="<? echo "$row[Reg_F_Name]" ?>"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Last Name:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="last" value="<? echo "$row[Reg_L_Name]" ?>"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Prayer Request</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="phone" value="<? echo "$row[Reg_Request]" ?>"></td>
    </tr>

</table>

</form>
```

Read more here from the [PHP manual.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php)

Comment: Thank you for your response! I make the changes you suggested and it is now pulling the info from the database. My next step is to have a button at the bottom of the page that says something like "Approve Prayer" which when clicked saves the changes made to the database. Any suggestions on how to perform this step? I've tried a few times but nothing worked correctly.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. For that you need to add a button to your `<form>` like `<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Approve Prayer'>` and on the other page , you need to write an `INSERT` query.

Comment: Okay I added the button and added this  query to the second file:  $query2="INSERT INTO Request (Reg_F_Name,Reg_L_Name,Reg_Request)";     My next task is to expand the text boxes so that it displays all the information and is not cut off. Is there any simple solution to this? Once again thanks for all your help.

Comment: It will be better if you opened another question and show the attempts , so we can easily help you out mate because it's hard to understand here :) and to read the code.